# Oracle update query set a value to true out of two values even when false is passed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following Oracle update query to set count and event hit.

```
update iam_counts
     set count = count + 1, event_hit = :eventHit
   where row_id = :rowId
```

Count is number type and event_hit is char type (T or F)

This query is called from two methods alternatively. Method 1 with event hit false and Method 2 with event hit true.

In both cases, count should be updated and for event hit it should be set to true like below

- Method 1 call - false
- Method 2 call - true
- Method 1 call - true ----> Even though event hit is false it should be set as true

Is there a functionality like check or query to achieve it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the condition to set it to true? Or do you want to to set it to true always? Then what does the parameter :eventHit do?

Comment: From method 1, event hit will be always false, and from method 2 it will be true. for eg,                                             if method 1 is called first, count will be 1 and event hit will be false and method 2 next, count will be 2 and event hit will be true and then if method 1 is again called it will have event hit as false but is should not update false... rather it should be true as it is in db.......... so it is not true always. but once set to true it should not be set to false again even if the call is from emthod 1

Comment: So you want event_hit to stay true once it has been set to true no matter what comes afterwards?

Comment: @MartinK. If it is set as true in DB and not updating again with false, then thats ok... It is my expectation. but the current logic will update it back to false if method 1 is called and executed the query.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. On the one hand you say "If it is set as true in DB and not updating again with false" but on the other hand you don't want your update to do what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
update iam_counts
set count = count + 1, 
event_hit = decode(event_hit, 'T', 'T', :eventHit)
where row_id = :rowId
```

event_hit will be updated if it is false, when it is true, it will stay the same.